Show specific apps depending on a start up app choice
I'd like to write an app that starts at startup when AndroidTV boots and, depending on the choice I make on this app, Android home has only specific apps.
I.e. if the startup app has a drop-down menu with two choices:

Newbie
Expert

When the user clicks on OK button, if it's a newbie user the home page will show up App1 and App2, if it's an expert, App3 and App4.
Can somebody point me to the right direction, i.e. link to start understanding how to do it or so?

Create your own launcher app, replacing the stock launcher that provides the existing home page.
